# Python memory issues with matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, colors, out-of-memory

I am creating a simulation of diffusion in a complex system taking arbitrary images as a substrate and allowing arbitrary creation of diffusion fronts and allowing both surface reactions as well as deposition of new material on the starting substrates. The results I'm quite proud of so far, and you can check out the movies I made with it here for CVD and SFD deposition on particles.

[CVD Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO78VK6Pyi4)

[SFD Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZflzCqku14)

Unfortunately I cannot generate more than 50 or so frames because it runs out of memory. I have tried clearing things as much as possible throughout the simulation, but I think I must be missing something. To summarize:

I start out by creating an empty list

```
ims = []
```

Then, each time my "simulation" runs, if `frame number % frame "rate" == 0`, it generates a frame which is:

- displayed using `plt.ion()` through `plt.draw()` and
- uses `ims.append()` to add the rendered plot to an array of animated frames.

Before each frame render, I run `plt.clf()` to prevent the plot from just having increasing numbers of overlaid plots.

Without the `ims.append()` step, the code consumes between 140 and 170MB of RAM. With that step, **50 frames consumes nearly 1.4GB of RAM**. Obviously, this is very limiting. 50 frames is nice, but I'd really like at least 350. That may be impossible with this route, but this suggests a memory usage purely by the ims array of roughly 24MB per frame.

A workaround is to create the frame and render it to an `.svg` or `.png` file inside the loop and save it to disk. I find that this rendering process is very CPU intensive so doing that often makes the code quite slow. Additionally, creating 350 PNG files and then converting them manually into a video is pretty messy, so I'd love to somehow get it all inside of the program itself.

Does anyone have an idea for how to decrease the memory usage of this example code without resorting to rendering and writing each frame to disk?

In this toy code, I just used a random number generator to populate the two datasets as described in the comments to speed things up.

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *
import time

# Defines the number of frames of animation to render.
outputframes = 50

# Defines the size of the canned simulation.
nx = 800
ny = 800

# Defines the number of actual simulation timesteps
nt = 100

# This gets the number of timesteps between outputframes.
framestep = 2

# For reporting.
framenum = 0

# Creates two steps, one for the stepped simulated step,
# and one for the prior state. There are two independently
# changing materials, each of which will have half the simulation
# space containing random values here, plus 10% overlap in the
# middle.

p1 = zeros((nx, ny, 2))
p1[360:800,:,0] = random.rand(440, ny)
p2 = zeros((nx, ny, 2))
p2[0:440,:,0] = random.rand(440, ny)

# Animation colormap setup
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax = 1)
# And sets up two corresponding colormaps, one blue and one
# red for p1 and p2 respectively (goal is overlaid).
cmap1 = cm.Blues
cmap2 = cm.Reds

# Sets up an empty array to hold animation frames.
ims = []

# Sets up and uses ion to draw the figure without blocking.
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
plt.draw()

# Run the simulation.

for t in range(nt):
    # This looks to see how far we are, and if we're at a point
    # where t is an even multiple of framestep, we should render
    # a new frame.

    if (t%framestep == 0):
        print('Frame ' + str(framenum))
        framenum = framenum + 1
        plt.clf()
        # In here I did a bunch of stuff to get special colors in
        # the colormap to get substrates and surfaces and other
        # features clearly identified. I am creating a new frame1
        # and frame2 object because in reality I will be doing a
        # log plot math to convert to the graphic frame.
        frame1 = p1[:,:,0]

        # This part is necessary in my real program because
        # I manually modify the colormap after it's created
        # to include the above mentioned special colors.
        frame1_colors = cmap1(norm(frame1))

        # This is my (not quite right) attempt to do overlaid plots.
        plt.imshow(frame1_colors, alpha = 0.5)

        # Do the same for the second set of data.
        frame2 = p2[:,:,0]
        frame2_colors = cmap2(norm(frame2))

        # The goal here was to take the combined output and make
        # it into an animation frame to append to ims, the image
        # array.

        # This is where I start to run into problems. Without the
        # ims.append, the program has constant memory usage. With
        # it, I am using 1340MB by the 50th frame. This is the
        # biggest issue. Even throwing away all other simulation
        # data, this image array for animation is *enormous*.

        # With the ims.append line replaced with the plt.imshow
        # line alone, memory usage is much smaller, ranging from
        # 140-170MB depending on execution point, but relatively
        # constant.

        ims.append([plt.imshow(frame2_colors, alpha = 0.5)])
#        plt.imshow(frame2_colors, alpha = 0.5)

        # Then try to draw updating animation to show progress
        # using draw(). As best I can tell, this basically works,
        # in that the plot is displaying with all components.
        plt.draw()


    # I'll put in a timer so that this doesn't go too fast, since
    # the actual calculation is very complex.
    time.sleep(0.01)

    # Proxy for the actual calculation. Just overwrite with new
    # random data in the overlapping ranges to show some change
    # visually.
    p1[360:800,:,1] = random.rand(440, ny)
    p2[0:440,:,1] = random.rand(440, ny)

    # In this version, it is trivial, but in the real simulation
    # p1[:,:,1] does not end up equal to p1[:,:,0], so the following
    # resets the simulation for the next timestep, overwriting the
    # old values to avoid memory overflow from the p1 and p2 arrays
    # being enormous.

    # Copy new values into old values.
    p1[:,:,0] = p1[:,:,1]
    p2[:,:,0] = p2[:,:,1]

# This is just a repeat for the final frame.
plt.clf()
frame1 = p1[:,:,0]
frame1_colors = cmap1(norm(frame1))
plt.imshow(frame1_colors, alpha = 0.5)
frame2 = p2[:,:,0]
frame2_colors = cmap2(norm(frame2))

# As above, the ims.append uses tons of memory, the imshow alone works well.
ims.append([plt.imshow(frame2_colors, alpha = 0.5)])
# plt.imshow(frame2_colors, alpha = 0.5)

plt.draw()

anim = anim.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, blit=True)
anim.save('test.mp4', fps=10, writer='avconv')
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt at detail, but you've made this too much for the kind of questions that Stack Overflow specializes in.

Comment: I removed the second question. You're welcome to ask it, but please do so in another question. All the text is available in the history. I've also edited your question to try and make it more digestible. If you dislike any style changes, feel free to revert them. Because of me removing the second question, it might be a good idea to remove mentions of it from the source code, which is a bit large at the moment.

Comment: Oh, and do you really mean **1.4TB** of RAM? Not **1.4GB**?

Comment: Thank you for editing it down to be better suited. Making each post a very distinct question is a better way for sure. And yes, I meant 1.4GB, I will update the post to match.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ModestImage appears to address an issue of this kind.
Indeed, high-resolution images without compression are VERY large. Maybe offload them to disk or compress in-memory?

Comment: Hmm, thanks Ivan. That looks promising. It seems thought that since my image isn't really "high resolution" (it is only 800x800, and I really do want the full image as I have single pixel wide features), the description looks questionable.

It seems like the best solution might be image saving of the current plot for each frame in a file, and then using avconv to merge them into a video at the end and delete the original images. I suppose this isn't a huge surprise, I guess I was just hoping that since I can export each frame as a 22kB PNG it could maybe internally represent it that way.

Comment: You could save the PNG to a byte string, although I'm not sure how you'd use that to generate a video.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided the only reasonable way to do this was by rendering each frame I needed to disk as a .png and then generating a movie from the images afterwards with avconv.

Thanks for all the suggestions, but it looks like this is just a limitation due to the RAM usage of uncompressed images.